# Calculating using sass variables for properties with multiple values

Tags: css, sass

I have two sass variables I'm using to set different sets of margin values as follows:

```
$variable-big: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem;

$variable-small: 1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;
```

I'm a total novice sass user from a design background so please bear with me if I get the terminology wrong in describing my problem and I'm just being stupid in something that is probably obvious to other users.

I want to be able to have a new variable to calculate the difference between the two sets of values.

So something like this...

```
$variable-difference: $variable-big - $variable-small
```

So that I can use it like this

```
.spacer-top {
margin: $variable-difference;
}
```

To output this:

```
.spacer-top {
margin: 1.4rem 0.3rem 1.1rem 0.1rem;
}
```

I've been trying to read up on how to do this and have tried various things to little success:

```
$variable-difference: $variable-big - $variable-small
```

returns: margin: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem-1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;

```
$variable-difference: ($variable-big) - ($variable-small)
```

returns the same: margin: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem-1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;

```
$variable-difference: ($variable-big - $variable-small)
```

the same: margin: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem-1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;

```
 $variable-difference: (#{$variable-big} - #{$variable-small})
```

the same: margin: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem-1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;

Self-evidently, I don't know what I'm doing. 
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those variables are actually lists, you may use the `nth(<list>, <index>)` function to retrieve the n<sup>th</sup> element of a list ([Doc](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method))

```
$variable-big: 2.5rem 1rem 1.8rem 1.2rem;
$variable-small: 1.1rem 0.7rem 0.7rem 0.1rem;


div {
   margin: 
   nth($variable-big, 1) - nth($variable-small, 1)
   nth($variable-big, 2) - nth($variable-small, 2)
   nth($variable-big, 3) - nth($variable-small, 3)
   nth($variable-big, 4) - nth($variable-small, 4);
}


/* Output

div {
    margin: 1.4rem 0.3rem 1.1rem 1.1rem;
}
*/
```

> [SassMeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/5be54465356f0c4dc030df3ce77ac2d5)

Further reference on lists [in this article](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/) by Hugo Giraudel

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you so much for your help.